# How to make URL (link) that works like filling in a text box and clicking a button?

Tags: html, url

On a 3rd party homepage there is a button like:

```
<INPUT class="widget-content" TYPE="TEXT" onchange="javascript:document.foo.submit();" NAME="RegExRef">
```

I want to automate the process of filling in the text box and clicking the button.

Is it possible to make a URL (link), that works like I filled in the text box and clicked the button?

For example, the home page http://lazycackle.com/Probability_of_repeated_event_online_calculator__birthday_problem_.html has two text boxes with HTML:

```
<input type="text" size="9" id="m1value" onkeyup="v1Change()" onchange="v1Change()"/>m <br/>
<input type="text" size="9" id="n1value" onkeyup="v1Change()" onchange="v1Change()"/>n <br/>
```

So I want to make an URL where the values for these two input boxes are automatically filled out when I go to the page through that URL (link) in the browser.

Comment: Much of this seems ambiguous. What text box? Is this text input a button visually? Do you want a button clicked or a form submitted? But yes, any/all of that is pretty easy. I just don't quite understand exactly what you want, so can't provide an accurate code example.

Comment: I have added an example to show that I mean.

Comment: That will only work if that 3rd party site actively supports this.

Comment: CBroe is correct. I didn't process that you don't have access to the site source.

Comment: BitwiseCreative and @CBroe: Thanks, also a help to know that it is not possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

yes that is possible, you can use [this](http://gabinaureche.com/TheaterJS/) library to create a typing effect, looks like human typed it

here is a demo http://codepen.io/Zhouzi/pen/JoRazP?editors=001
Ex:

```
var theater = new TheaterJS();
theater
  .describe("Vader", { speed: .8, accuracy: .6, invincibility: 4 }, "#vader")
    theater.write(
        {
          name: "say",
          args: ["That's impossible!", false]
        }
      );
```